# How to add headers using LibCURL in julia

Tags: julia, libcurl

I want to make a post api call , and set the curl content-type header to application/json,

Update:
  My project uses Julia Version 0.4.7 on Linux (x86_64), and Aplication get  stuck at curl_slist_append function call.

This is how my code snippet looks`slist = Ref{Ptr{Void}}() ; slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: application/json") ;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to create object `LibCURL.curl_slist` and set it as `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option.

However, whenever possible you will have a much better Julia experience by using `HTTP.jl`:

```
julia> using HTTP; d = HTTP.request(:GET, "https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1",["hfoo"=>"hbar"]);

julia> println(String(d.body))
{"args":{"foo1":"bar1"},"headers":{"x-forwarded-proto":"https","x-forwarded-port":"443","host":"postman-echo.com","x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-5ec438fa-c2bf3d5d8a300e08685f833d","content-length":"0","hfoo":"hbar","user-agent":"HTTP.jl/1.4.1"},"url":"https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1"}
```

If you want actually use `LibCURL.jl` here is the code:

Setup:

```
using LibCURL

curl = curl_easy_init()
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1")
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)

pars = "hfoo: hbar"
header = LibCURL.curl_slist(pointer(pars), Ptr{Nothing}())
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header)



function curl_write_cb(curlbuf::Ptr{Cvoid}, s::Csize_t, n::Csize_t, p_ctxt::Ptr{Cvoid})
    sz = s * n
    data = Array{UInt8}(undef, sz)
    ccall(:memcpy, Ptr{Cvoid}, (Ptr{Cvoid}, Ptr{Cvoid}, UInt64), data, curlbuf, sz)
    println("recd: ", String(data))
    sz::Csize_t
end

c_curl_write_cb = @cfunction(curl_write_cb, Csize_t, (Ptr{Cvoid}, Csize_t, Csize_t, Ptr{Cvoid}))
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, c_curl_write_cb)
```

Testing:

```
julia> res = curl_easy_perform(curl)
recd: {"args":{"foo1":"bar1"},"headers":{"x-forwarded-proto":"http","x-forwarded-port":"80","host":"postman-echo.com","x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-5ec441ed-4d77afc5035df618da4b4bb6","accept":"*/*","hfoo":"hbar"},"url":"http://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1"}
0x00000000
```

Comment: thanks @Przemyslaw Szufel , this works for Julia1.x perfectly , my project is based on Julia Version 0.4.7 Linux (x86_64) and the applcations get stuck at curl_slist_append function call

Comment: Dear @Nikhil Navin  - 0.4.7 is a very old version and I assume most libraries will not work with it any more. All I can advice you here is to try to upgrade (if possible).